# java.sql.SQLException: Could not open connection to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hiveql

I am trying to setup a jdbc connection to the my hive! I am facing this error while trying to connect to the hiveserver2.
Any help over this would be really helpful! thanks

Also, here is my jdbc driver and the connection URL

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Could not open connection to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:206)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:178)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at play.readere.main(readere.java:98)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:129)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.receiveSaslMessage(TSaslTransport.java:178)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport.open(TSaslTransport.java:288)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport.open(TSaslClientTransport.java:37)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openTransport(HiveConnection.java:203)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:127)
    ... 10 more


Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "hive", "");

"org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"
```

Comment: Are you sure what's listening on port 10000 is your database server? Looks like it's something else.

Comment: When I ran the hiveserver2 and check the netstat for port 10000, it wasn't there! There was no entry for port 10000!

Comment: So do you think that I might have missed something in the hiveserver2 configuration? I haven't changed anything in configuration related to hiveserver2

Comment: It seems like my hiveserver in closing the connection immediately after the connection. I have tried to set the hive.read.socket.timeout and also hive.server.tcp.keepalive properties in hive-site.xml!